# python tkinter: grid sticky not working when multiple frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# Select Country Dropdown Menu
frame_country = tk.Frame(root, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
frame_country.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(0,5), sticky="nsew")

label_country_dropdown = ttk.Label(frame_country, text="Country:")
label_country_dropdown.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

dropdown_country = ttk.Combobox(frame_country)
dropdown_country.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="e")
countriesList = ["Spain", "Romania"]
dropdown_country["values"] = countriesList


# Select Municipality Dropdown Menu
frame_municipality = tk.Frame(root, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
frame_municipality.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

label_municipality_dropdown = ttk.Label(frame_municipality, text="Municipality:")
label_municipality_dropdown.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

dropdown_municipality = ttk.Combobox(frame_municipality)
dropdown_municipality.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="e")
municipalitiesList = ["Madrid", "Bucarest"]
dropdown_municipality["values"] = municipalitiesList


root.mainloop()
```

That produces this result:

[image]

The country dropdown menu is not aligned to the right although I used `sticky="e"`.

If I change `"Municipality"` to `"Foo"` the result is the oposite:

[image]

Probably any widget is well aligned.

Comment: You can grow an item to fill all the available space horizontally using `sticky='ew'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't configured the columns in `frame_country` so the gridder doesn't know how to allocate extra space. By default it doesn't use any extra space, so the frame is just big enough to fit the data in the two columns.

A good rule of thumb is to always give at least one row and one column a positive weight for a widget that uses grid to manage it's children. In this specific case, that means you should give a weight of 1 to the column where the dropdown is.

```
frame_country.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

This will tell the gridder that any extra space is to be allocated to column 1.